# Raw Field Value in Views

Tags: views, 8, theming

We have a content type that has a Video Embed Field. In this field, we simply enter youtube or Vimeo url.

In a custom view we are trying to display the raw value of the field. 
Since this is a Video Embed Field, the only formatter in Views are to display the video or a thumbnail of it.

The problem is that we want to display just the raw value of this field which will be the video url.

Are there any workarounds that will allow us to display the raw value of this field when added in a view? [image]

Comment: Is there a token (replacement pattern) for the video URL in the Field settings when you uncollapse the `Rewrite results` and `Replacement patterns`? You can use this feature to display different "aspects" of a field. I expect to find the URL token there.

Comment: It worked. Thank you.

Comment: I'll add an answer for future reference, so it's easier for others who search for the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different Field information can be displayed in Views by using the **`Rewrite results`** and `Replacement patterns` options in the Field configuration.

Different Field data is usually available as tokens (replacement patterns) that can be used to construct a different output than those available under the Formatter option.

Here's an example for displaying the image Alt text instead of the actual image:

[image: Drupal Image Alt Rewrite results in Views]

It works similarly for the Video field, and many others too.